# Can't determine cause of segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

A part of my program is wrong and causes segmentation fault. So I'm coming up with a program that reads in a bunch of data about student records like ID, and their corresponding grades and credits. This data is stored in a text file. Then, as the data is read in, my program creates a linked list of the student records, sorted by unique ID. Since the ID of the student may be repeated again in the text file, I created a function to search for duplicates, and this function is not correct somewhere, causing segmentation fault. Here is the function:

```
struct SR *findDuplicate ( struct SR *head, int ID )
    {
        struct SR *temp = NULL;
        temp = malloc ( sizeof ( head ) );
        temp = head;
        while ( temp->ID != ID )
        {
            if ( temp->next != NULL )
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else 
            return NULL;
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

So when I run the debugger, it returns this error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400deb in findDuplicate (head=0x7fffffffe540, ID=5304) at HW7.c:101
101                     while ( temp->ID != ID )
```

And I can't figure out what's wrong with the while loop. Somewhere up in the program, I've initialized head.ID to be -1 ( since the IDs of the student in the text file is never negative ) and head.next to be NULL. I can't figure out what's wrong with the logic of this code.

Edit 1: I've initialized head like this ( in main ):

```
struct SR head;

    head.ID = -1;
    head.next = NULL;
    head.ID = 0;head.GPA = 0;head.numCredits = 0;head.numCoursesTakenSoFar = 0; 
    head.GPApoints = 0;
```

and this function is called from another function which is called from main:

I called this function like this:

```
ind_1 = findDuplicate ( first, a );
```

ind_1 is declared as a pointer to a struct.

The function that calls findDuplicate is the processInput function, so a is a variable that reads in the student ID from the text file.

Edit 2: From main I call a function called processInput which part of it looks like this ( until the first call of findDuplicate ):

```
void processInput ( struct SR *first, char str [50] )
{
    char ch;    
    int a, b, x=0;
    struct SR *ind_1;
    FILE *fp;               
    fp = fopen ( str, "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {       printf("Can't open file\n");            
        exit ( 1 );                                 
    }
    while ( fscanf ( fp, "%d %d %c", &a, &b, &ch ) != EOF )     
    {
        ind_1 = findDuplicate ( first, a );
```

From main, processInput is called like this:

```
processInput ( &head, argv [i+1] );
```

I hope this is enough information. The program is really long and I don't want to put too much code. Therefore, first is a pointer to head, and the address of head is passed from main to processInput.

Comment: What's the point of the `malloc` call? All it does is leak memory. Also are you sure that `head` is pointing to valid memory?

Comment: In main, I've declared head as a struct variable, and initialized all its corresponding members. That should work out, right?

Comment: `memcpy` from `head` to `temp`? Why malloc at all? Size of allocated memory is wrong: you pick size of pointer, not struct.

Comment: I'm not sure. I added that line thinking that the temp pointer somehow needs memory for that, but I'm confused. I'm new to structs. Does a struct pointer need memory also?

Comment: The first 3 lines of your function could be simplified to `struct SR *temp = head;` (which would also remove the memory leak you have right now). So you need to show how you initialize `head` and how you call the function, the error is most likely there

Comment: You do not have to allocate memory when you are assigning a pointer to point to memory that is already allocated.  That includes when you are using the assignment operator to make a pointer to point to the same thing that a different pointer points to.

Comment: The debugger is telling you that the segfault arises from evaluating the `while` predicate.  That only makes sense if the current value of `temp` is not a valid pointer.  Nothing in the code you have presented explains why that might be, so present a [mcve] if you want further assistance.

Comment: @Lim LS  Where is the variable first assigned?

Comment: `temp = malloc ( sizeof *temp );`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow In main

Comment: @LimLS, how about you fix the `malloc()` issue in your code (as UnholySheep described), so that people will stop commenting on that irrelevancy?

Comment: @JohnBollinger That;s precisely why. I don't understand why temp is not a valid pointer. I've assigned it to point to head, and I've initialized all the members of the struct in head

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok, sorry.

Comment: @LimLS Show the minimum snippet of the code with all initializations. For example I do not understand this      head.ID = -1;

    head.ID = 0

Comment: @LimLS: MCVE.  You still have not provided one.  Follow the link I provided above if you're uncertain what that would entail.  But for what it's worth, `temp` probably becomes invalid on the second or a subsequent iteration of the loop.  That is, your data structure is probably corrupt.

Comment: The code you added doesn't make sense - you show how you initialize a variable named `head` but then you call the function using `first`, which you don't show how it is initialized

Comment: What is `first`?  You've created a variable named `head`, but you're passing a variable named `first`?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem could be this.

See basically head is just a pointer pointing to some memory location. You have to make sure head is pointing to legitimate node of your linked list. If head is NULL then head->id or temp->id would be illegal generating core dump. Also note that temp is also just a pointer , you do not need to malloc it. Just plain assign it to head .
See below:

```html
struct SR *findDuplicate ( struct SR *head, int ID )
    {
        struct SR *temp = NULL; // Pointer 4 bytes
        
        temp = head; // Assign value(address) of head to temp
        while ( temp && temp->ID != ID ) // Check if temp is NULL first
        {
            if ( temp->next != NULL )
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else 
            return NULL;
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you're leaking memory from the malloc in your code.

This said, running your example code as follows doesn't crash for me.  To make it clear, I don't think this implementation of findDuplicate is good (it leaks memory, and it is overly verbose).  However it isn't incorrect as such (memory leak notwithstanding): you're allocating space for a pointer, setting that pointer, and then dereferencing that pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct SR {
    struct SR *next;
    int ID;
};

struct SR *findDuplicate ( struct SR *head, int ID )
{
    struct SR *temp = NULL;
    temp = malloc ( sizeof ( head ) );
    temp = head;
    while ( temp->ID != ID )
    {
        if ( temp->next != NULL )
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    return temp;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct SR head = { .next = NULL, .ID = -1 };
    struct SR *found = findDuplicate(&head, 42);
    free(found);
    return 0;
}
```

I would therefore suggest the while loop in your processInput snippet in the question is probably to blame.  I imagine that you're doing something with 'first' if findDuplicate returns NULL, and that probably corrupts the list.

I think you probably need to review your memory handling approach in the program.  I don't understand why findDuplicate needs to allocate memory -- I would have expected memory for struct SR to be allocated if findDuplicate finds no existing entry for ID on the linked list.

If you post complete example code and input data it would help narrow down your exact issue.

Comment: Only by the grace of God, and the spurious nature of **Undefined Behavior** does it not crash for you. Let me guess... You haven't checked by running the executable through `valgrind` or similar memory error checking program -- have you? What is passed as the *first parameter* to `findDuplicate`? (hint: *a pointer*). What is `sizeof (head)`? (hint: `sizeof (a pointer)`) Is `sizeof (a pointer)` enough memory to store **both** a `pointer` and an `int`? (I'll let you answer that one...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin To answer your final question: no, `sizeof(a pointer)` isn't enough memory to store both a pointer and an int.  In `findDuplicate`, `temp` points to `sizeof(a pointer)` bytes, and is then set to `head` (again, a pointer).  It is then dereferenced.  So no UB that I can see, just a memory leak as others have pointed out.  I'm not saying this implementation is good; I've copied it from the OP's post to demonstrate it runs without segfaulting and as an example of how to give a complete and useful code snippet for others to try.  I have indeed run my program through valgrind.

Comment: Chuckling.., Tom, I apologize, I was a bit curt in my comment and it was not intended to offend, but I wanted to take you though the thought process that showed where the error lay in a clear and concise manner. That's the nebulous thing about **undefined behavior** (it's like a box of chocolates), you never know what you are going to get. That is why it has to be protected against so thoroughly. `valgrind` will clearly show an attempted `write` and `read` `0-bytes` beyond an allocated block of `8-bytes`. The reason the segfault isn't guaranteed is there may be no conflict for that space - yet

Comment: Thanks David, no offence taken.  I had read your reasoning as "you're trying to store the *contents* of `struct SR` in the allocated space", which the code isn't doing. This said I take your wider point about UB which I understand in this case is due to `struct SR *temp` pointing to a memory block the size of a pointer, NOT the size of `struct SR`.  I think this is an example of *Violating Type Rules* from here: http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html .  Anyway, thanks again for commenting, I appreciate it.